# Getting the average over the first n rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, average, mean

I'm trying to devise a sql query that can take a column of results and return the average/mean of the first "n" results.

In other words, if I have a sample of data that looks like this:

```
|  Day  | Number of People |
|:-----:|:----------------:|
| 12/01 |         4        |
| 12/02 |         8        |
| 12/03 |         5        |
| 12/04 |         6        |
| 12/05 |         8        |
| 12/06 |         3        |
| 12/07 |         5        |
```

I want a query that can result in the table looking like this:

```
|  Day  | Number of People |  nMean |
|:-----:|:----------------:|:------:|
| 12/01 |         4        |    4   |
| 12/02 |         8        |    6   |
| 12/03 |         5        | 5.6667 |
| 12/04 |         6        |  5.75  |
| 12/05 |         8        |   6.2  |
| 12/06 |         3        | 5.6667 |
| 12/07 |         5        | 5.5714 |
```

Answer (score 4):

You can have a very elegant solution if you use window functions.
This though only works in SQL Server 2012 and later.

```
SELECT d.[day], 
AVG(d.[num] * 1.0) OVER
(
     ORDER BY d.[day] ASC
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
     AND CURRENT ROW
) AS nMean
FROM [data] d;
```

This should work too (even in SQL Server 2008):

```
select d2.[day], avg(1.0 * d1.num) as nMean
from
data d2 
join data d1 on d2.day >= d1.day
group by d2.[day]
order by d2.[day] asc;
```

Comment: @radar Yes, I just realized that too. It requires SQL Server 2012, I think.

Comment: hmmm..you did it again. 2008 version is much simpler.

Comment: @radar ... but not sure if that efficient ;)